# Getting control reaches end of non-void function warning though I have return statements in th functions?

Tags: c++

I am compiling a c++ NodeList class and I am getting the warning "control reaches end of non void function" but I do have return statements in the functions that give the error and I am not clear of what is causing the error.

I have tried putting a return statement inside a for loop, which should work by breaking out of the function once it reaches it, and also trying to use a separate pointer.

```
DataType * ArrayList::insertAfter(const DataType & target,const DataType & value){   // *This function replaces an array element with a parameter (DataType objects)* //
    for(size_t i = 0 ; i < m_size ; i++){
        if (m_array[i] == target){
                    m_array[i+1] = value;
                    return &m_array[i+1];
                }

    }   
}
```

I expect the files to compile but the warnings prevents this.

Comment: What if the `if` condition is never satisfied or the `for` loop never runs?

Comment: @Tomothy32 yes duh thank you

Comment: @Tomothy32 Please consider making an answer to get this out of the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 1):

Turning my comment into an answer:

The `return` might not execute if the `if` condition is never satisfied or the `for` loop never runs.

Therefore, you should return some default value after the end of the `for` loop (maybe `nullptr` in this case?). Another option is throwing an exception.